# Google Map not loading in bootstrap modal in React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am currently working on react application. I am using bootstrap modal for display google-map but it's not rendered if I resize the window it gets loaded properly. Is there any way to render?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you kindly provide more details? React version,  which google-map api etc

Comment: Hi Matthew, I am using react version 15.6.1 & google-map api version 3

Comment: You should put this details and source code in the question. If you want to help us in helping you, uploading the code on codepen would really facilities our time in trying to figure out what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Hey Hi, I have added code here. please check https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/86299/

Comment: Did you manage to run the code in jsfiddle? I had plenty of errors in the console low. One of them related to React which makes me suspicious the jsfiddle is not set up correctly